# Parse book-ended character-delimited strings of variable length using regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have a block of text that contains a number of comment tags:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<--this is a comment-->, consectetur adipiscing<--replace=>with this--> elit. Maecenas massa ip<---123=<--=>+456>=->-->sum, ultrices quis semper porttitor, cursus at lectus.`

I want to write a regular expression that will capture the contents of all instances of `<--xxx=>yyy-->` tags.  From the above text, this would return `[('replace', 'with this'), ('-123=<--', '+456>=->')]`.  The problem is that the text and comments can contain any number of any combination of character (with the exception of the comment tag delimiters of `<--`, `-->` and `=>`).

Is it possible to accomplish this with a single regular expression?  I am using Python to test this, but the regex should work on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a working regexp according to your updated matching requirements:

```
/<--((?:[^=-]|(?:=(?!>)|-(?!->)))+)=>((?:[^=-]|(?:=(?!>)|-(?!->)))+)-->/g
```

This filters the delimiters `-->`, `<--`, `=>` which are not allowed within the capture groups. Note the `g` modifier for global matching. Extract both groups for each match to get the desired result.

([RegExr](http://regexr.com?33erj))

Comment: This works for the example text, but does not cover all of the necessary scenarios.  The regex needs to be able to match any combination of ascii characters.

Comment: @willOEM "Any combination of ascii characters" would also include the delimiters `<--`, `=>`, and `-->`. But I guess that these shouldn't be part of a comment. Please be more specific about what is allowed and what not.

Comment: Yes, you are spot on.  The idea is that the desired text can contain any character, including those used in the delimiters, but the combination of characters that makes the tags should never occur in the comment.  So far this regex is matching all of my tests, thanks!